# How to ignore hidden column in MS Excel input in pentaho jobs?

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration, pentaho-report-designer, pentaho-design-studio

In my source extracts having only 16 columns by default.

1. in my first file having 4 hidden columns between sitename and
   campaignname.
2. in my second file having 2 hidden columns between sitename and
   campaignname
3. like wise my all the file columns are hideing different different
   format.
   Please refer images which i attached.File 1 [image].. File 2 [image]
4. So how to make a single pentaho job for all the files loading. Could
   you please help ? thanks.

Comment: How many tables have you. The response is going to be quite different if you have two input Excel files or having 1000 files each with a different format.

Comment: I am receiving more than 100 files for daily basis with different format excel.

Comment: Do you have anyway to know which columns have to be eleminated (other than the fact that they are hidden)? For example they are empty or have no name or have a name not in SiteName, CampaignName, PackageName,...

Answer (score 0):

**Small number of files:**
As you seem to have only two files, the easiest is probably to swallow the two Excel files with their respective format, then to use a `Select values` to keep only the relevant columns and merge them for the rest of the transform.

It is possible with the PDI to merge two (or more) input flow, but it requires the input to have exactly the same metadata (same columns, same names, same type,...), which is done with a `Select value`.

[image]

**Large number of files:**

If you have a large number of files, you have to read them without a column name (i.e., with no header) calling the columns A, B, C, D,... Then filter out the coumns you are not interested in, and change the metadata.

For the last you may use a `Metadata Injection Step`.